# Installing a local Python package dynamically

Tags: python, setuptools

I'm building [a small Python package](https://github.com/IttayEyal/memoization) with a friend.

```
.
├── __init__.py
└── memoized.py
```

During the development process, I want to test the installed package - for example, to make sure that some `__init__.py` code runs as expected.

The current way to achieve this is:

1. Create a virtualenv on `/tmp`
2. Activate it
3. `cd` to the repo dir
4. `python setup.py install`
5. `cd` elsewhere (to avoid importing from the directory instead of importing from the installed package)
6. Test the import
7. `pip uninstall memoized`
8. Repeat steps 3-7

This is long and cumbersome, and I vaguely remember there's a way to install a package in a way that does not copy its code to the virtualenv, but links to it instead. This way changing the code would be reflected at the next import, without re-installing.

I've searched for "Dynamic importing" and alike but it refers to a different feature.

**How can I install a local Python package so that changes to the package code would be immediately reflected?**

Comment: Did you create `setup.py` file ? Working in development mode is done with `python setup.py develop`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could activate the virtualenv first and navigate to the project directory. Then run

```
pip install --editable .
```

[`--editable`](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/cli/pip_install/#cmdoption-e) install a project in editable mode and [uses current working directory instead of copying the source code](https://youtu.be/kNke39OZ2k0?t=151).